# Повторная отсылка формы

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение такой проблемы. Пользователь заполняет форму, жмет ОТПРАВИТЬ (метод POST), затем скрипт обрабатывает и INSERT'ом вставляет в базу. Но тут косяк: если в браузере нажать "обновить" или F5, то добавляется одна и та же запись. Положил гирьку на F5 и сервак упал от переизбытка чувств (записей). Как избежать повторной отсылки формы? Уже специально очищаю массив $_POST. Вот выдержка из кода

```
function insert_thing(){
   if (!empty($_POST)) {INSERT (я тут не расписываю, не в этом суть)}
   $_POST=array();
   }
```

Т.е. вставляю в базу и очищаю $_POST, однако, он ни фига не очищается! And so on and on!

Comment: Это разумеется не ответ, но как вариант - начинать переходить на AJAX.

Comment: И плюс. Не всегда применимо, но в большинстве случаев поможет именно это..

Answer (score 5):

```
function insert_thing(){
   if (!empty($_POST)) {INSERT (я тут не расписываю, не в этом суть)}
   while (ob_end_clean()){};
   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit;
   }
```

Переадресовываем юзера на эту же страницу GET-запросом, т.е. F5 повторит уже GET. Там же можно вставить результат (**`'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?success='.intval($result)`**)

Comment: Объясните, пожалйста, в чём смысл цикла и что за функция ob_end_clean?

Comment: Если ранее была начата буферизация (<a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php">ob_start()</a>) эта функция очищает все, что было до нее, чтобы нормально отправить заголовок Location. А цикл пустой, т.к. при очистке буфера `ob_end_clean` дает true, а если нечего очищать - false.

Comment: `ob_start()` создает в стеке буфферов новый буффер, в который будут помещаться весь сгенерированный после его вызова контент, данная функция позволяет организовать кэширование частей генерируемой страницы. Цикл с ob_end_clean() - проходит по стеку и очищает все заполненные буфферы, таким образом не будет ошибки возникающей при отправке заголовков после контента.

Comment: Единственно мне кажется, стоит дать возможность скрипту выполняться после завершения соединения с клиентом, и редиректить клиента раньше чем начинается основная логика, так будет меньше вероятность возникновения дубликатов. Разумеется это если основная логика отрабатывает не быстро.

Comment: Браузер будет ждать отработки скрипта. Если не выйти, логика все равно пройдет, т.е. ожидание будет. Потому лучше просто забить адрес редиректа в переменную, а в конце работы скрипта, но до вывода, вставить вот эти 3 строчки.

Comment: @Sh4dow, Забавно, раньше я думал соединение рвется, выполнение скрипта завершается. А тут потестировал, оказалось, что даже если нажать стоп, а потом F5 то все равно оба из них выполнятся до конца. Более того, скрипт продолжал выполняется даже после закрытия браузера. Если интересно вот тестовый скрипт:

    // Симулируем задержку при отработке сложной логики
    $startTime = time();

    while (time() - $startTime < 20) 
        sleep(1);

    file_put_contents($startTime, 'bla-bla');

Comment: Добавлю, что новая Опера - довольно странный зверек, поэтому `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` может перекинуть на пустую страницу. Но вот `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&success=1');` уже перекинет правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, есть еще вариант выдавать каждой из форм уникальный строковый идентификатор. Помещать его в форму как hidden input. Завести в MySQL табличку, в которую заносить эти самые уникальные идентификаторы обработанных форм в течении последнего часа (временной интервал по вкусу). При получении формы проверяем не была ли форма с таким идентификатором уже обработана, если не была то заносим ее в таблицу (реализовать это, желательно, при помощи хранимой процедуры, так будут блокировки быстрее отрабатываться), иначе просто игнорируем пришедшие данные и выводим пользователю страницу. Генерировать уникальные строковые идентификаторы также лучше при помощи хранимой процедуры в MySQL.

Итак, теперь про реализацию самой таблицы. Впринципе нужна таблица с двумя полями (formID char(20), processed TIMESTAMP). Движок для этой таблицы лучше выбрать MEMORY - он серьезно ускорит данный процесс ([полезная ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/hi/108457/)). Так же стоит сделать два индекса: один - formID (нужен будет для проверки была ли обработана данная форма или нет), второй - processed (нужен для того чтобы убивать устаревшие, не нужные данные, например, formID обработанные более часа назад). Частоту, с которой удалять устаревшие данные можно взять по вкусу, но не слишком часто (раз в 15 минут я думаю будет достаточно).

P.S. почему не NoSQL? Да, просто по тому что пользователи чаще просто просматривают страницы, нежели отправляют формы, поэтому для более быстрой генерации нового formID потребуется большее кол-во чтений нежели записей (при обработки формы). К тому же, хостинг с MySQL дешевле :)

Comment: %) Понятно, что как хак сойдет, но вам не кажется, что это совсем адъ?) Я с этой штукой столкнулся на втором своем скрипте еще на php3, когда в опере тестил. Хотя мб функционал пригодится для намного более сложной задачи (если поля зависят от времени-id-ip-еще-чего-нибудь)

Comment: хм, честно говоря не вижу в этом ада :) хотя мб я привык к извращениям :) просто я не вижу другого способа бороться с F5 :(

Comment: Ну обычно просто хватает редиректа и блокировки форм мин на 5-30. Да, повторюсь, это юзабельно, но не для визиток и блогов имхо)

Comment: Насамом деле мне кажется стоит это просто превратить в модуль, т.е. один раз заморочиться, напрячься и упаковать в модуль чтобы он потом в пару кликов разворачивался :) и тогда уже будет все равно что блог, что магазин или форум)

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой большой и полезный ответ. Однако у меня нет опыта создания хранимых процедур и работы с типом MEMORY. И как осуществить генерацию уникального formID(я имею в виду алгоритм)?
Разбираться в этих темах пока нет времени - сроки поджимают.
А вообще возьму на вооружение: век живи - век учись. Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @waterman, обычно его генерят как какой-нибудь MD5 от склейки текщего времени в строковом представлении и случайного числа :) Сгенерировали, проверили, если есть еще раз сгенерировали, иначе выдали вкачестве результата :) ничего сложного :)

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивалась с такой же ерундой. Проблему решила вот таким образом:

1. К кнопке прикрутила условие куки - оно убирает кнопку после нажатия на определенное время (можете поставить любое, мне было актуально раз в сутки).
2. В файле обработчика расположила само это куки + сделала серверный редирект после обработки.

В результате после нажатия повторно на страничку обработчика не пустит кука, а обратный редирект не даст сработать кнопке ф5. Если жать стрелочку "назад", пользователь просто возвращается на предыдущую страницу без отправки формы. В живую выглядит так:

В файле формы

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie']))
{
echo "<center> <form method=\"post\" action=\"file.php\"> и тдтп ваша форма. </form></center>";
}
```

В файле обработчика:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include ("bd.php"); 
SetCookie("cookie",'1',time()+86400);
тра-ля-ля ваша обработка и в конце дописываем:

header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Все. Никакого ф5 =)

Answer (score 0):

А вы не думали при успешном добавлении делать редирект на страницу с уведомлением о добавлении? Либо блокировать пользователя (хотя бы на время) множественно отправившего одно и то же?

Ибо костыли типа очистки пост даты не есть хорошо.

Comment: Редирект - это хорошо. А как быть с кнопками ВПЕРЕД НАЗАД в браузерах? Если пользователь нажмет НАЗАД на странице с результатами о добавлении, то значения, введенные в inputax, никуда не деваются, жмём ДОБАВИТЬ и вуаля - та же самая запись опять идёт в базу, но уже под другим номером. То же и с кнопкой ВПЕРЕД. Ведь при нажатии на эти кнопки не происходит загрузка страницы, следовательно, не отрабатывают никакие скрипты! Как отследить такое поведение?

Answer (score 0):

Нормальные люди пользуются сериализацией данных и не делают костылей!
Почитайте про функцию serialize(), или же, делаейте unset($_POST) так он будет обнуляться.

Comment: И что сериализация и очистка формы даст в его случае? Это позволит не отсылать повторно данные по F5 в опере? о_О

Comment: Сериализация твой $_POST сделает строкой. Проверка is_array($_POST) и повторная отправка формы не произойдёт.

Comment: `<?php if(isset($_POST['s'])){echo '1';unset($_POST);}?><form action="" method="post"><input name="s" type="submit"></form>` - и ничего не обнуляется.

Comment: >> Сериализация твой $_POST сделает строкой. Проверка is_array($_POST) и повторная отправка формы не произойдёт. 

Вы не правы) форма заполняется на клиенте, запрос формируется там же. Отправили запрос - в ПОСТ данные - пхп очистил пост. Ф5 - отправили запрос - в ПОСТ данные - пхп очистил пост. Вы кажется просто механизм обработки запросов слабо себе представляете.

Comment: а что мешает задать сессионную переменную и записать в нее сериализованный пост? и сравнить потом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное всем участникам! Столько идей, кругом голова, надо как-нить испробовать их! Век живи, век учись!