# Запрет повторной отправки форм через F5

Tags: php, javascript

Если нажать F5, то все знают, что браузер спросит "Отправить ли форму еще раз?", как мне сделать на это запрет? Абсолютно для всех форм которые есть у меня на сайте.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK6R2.png

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Повторная отсылка формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23164/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

после принятия запроса и проведения манипуляций с данными,сделать редирект

Comment: Так же можно устанавливать куку после манипуляций с данными и при проверять ее наличие

Comment: Либо отправлять форму через AJAX)

Comment: либо очищать переменную,по которой проходит проверка данных формы))