# Сообщение при обновлении страницы

Tags: html

При обновлении страницы выскакивает сообщение:

На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?

Как я понимаю это из-за формы

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last:center;" name="name" onChange="this.form.submit();">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Подскажите как можно избавиться от него.

Comment: удалите форму )

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрет повторной отправки форм через F5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747901/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-f5)

Answer (score -1):

Измените событие ***beforeunload***

[beforeunload - Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)